# Laravel eloquent: Having and where in the same query but I want ti to be OR

Tags: mysql, eloquent

Is it possible to have **Having** and **Or Where** to function like `where field = 'text' or field2 = 'text'`

Basically I'm trying to create a function to be used to filter all the columns on a html table. For the data using **SUM()** I need to use **HAVING** if I filter using all columns the where clause will be like `where name like '%asdf%' or age like '%asdf%' or having SUM(quantity) like '%asdf%' group by id`

Comment: Unclear. WHERE and HAVING clauses are not dependent and may present in the query at the same time.

Comment: I want it to be OR not AND. I want it to display the results from the WHERE and display the results from the HAVING. is it possible?

Comment: Impossible. Use 2 queries combined with UNION.

Comment: Ok I just found the answer I'm looking for I can replace the where with having. Thanks

Comment: WHERE is processed before grouping, HAVING - after. I.e. the conditions in these clauses have different grouping level, so you cannot combine them in one expression.